# My farm has disappeared, what do I do?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I was in a group with some members of my guild and went to Valley of the Four Winds to check on my farm but it had disappeared, none of my plants are present!

I tried leaving the group I was in as we had just come out of a dungeon, so figured the group had perhaps been converted into a dungeon group and thus the phasing to my farm hadn't kicked in but this didn't sort the problem out either...

[image: Missing farm]

My farm has disappeared, what do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logging out of World of Warcraft (back to the character selection screen) resolved this issue for me. When I logged back in my farm was back in its original condition, with my plants at the stage they should have been at.

Comment: I've had this happen more than once now, the second time wasn't caused by being in a dungeon group - I was running solo and my crops still didn't appear. Relogging also resolved this instance of the problem as well...

Comment: Phasing issue I would assume.

Answer (score 1):

### Fly some distance away - then come back.

I gave this problem a good grilling because only one of my characters was failing.  I tried reloading the UI. Logging out. Changing toons (other characters were fine).  Quitting and restarting WoW.  Deleting the cache folder. Ditto *and* renaming Interface and WTF, giving the equivalent of a fresh installation.  Nothing worked.

I threw up my hands and restored my original Interface and WTF files, then I logged back in.

For other reasons, I flew/traveled over 200 yards* away from my farm.  **As I flew back and I got into visual range**, my crops re-appeared before my eyes!

*I have no idea what occurred technically, but it's very likely that it was *server-side* - because I did everything possible client-side.  Possibly a phasing issue. So leave Halfhill, and come back.*